# Taxonomy.php issue with search and filters

Tags: custom-taxonomy, query, search, query-posts

I'm trying to create a custom taxonomy.php page where my users can refine search into that context. I've tried to create a kind of loop like:

```
<?php 
                if(!empty($_GET['ending']))
                {
                    $ends = array(
                        'key' => 'ending',
                        'value' => (current_time('timestamp', 0) + 3600*24*$_GET['ending']),
                        //'type' => 'numeric',
                        'compare' => '<'
                    );
                }
                if(!empty($_GET['budgets']))
                {
                    $budgets = array(
                        'key' => 'budgets',
                        'value' => $_GET['budgets'],
                        //'type' => 'numeric',
                        'compare' => '='
                    );
                }
                $taxonomy = get_query_var('taxonomy');
                $post_per_page = 10;
                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'project',
                    'order' => 'DESC', 
                    'orderby' => 'date', 
                    'posts_per_page' => $post_per_page,
                    'paged' => 1, 
                    'meta_query' => array($closed, $ends, $budgets ),
                    's'=> GET('keyword'),
                    'post_status' =>array('publish'),
                    'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => $term->slug
                        )
                    )
                );
                query_posts($args);

                if ( have_posts() ): while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                    KleeiaDev_get_post(); 
                endwhile; 

                if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi')):
                    wp_pagenavi(); endif;

                wp_reset_postdata();

                else:
                    echo __('No projects posted here yet.',"KleeiaDev");
                endif;

                wp_reset_query();
                ?>
```

My elements that should filter the query are `$ends`, `$budgets` and `'s'=> GET('keyword')` which are connected to my side form like the following.

```
<form method="get" action="<?php echo $lnk ?>">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="<?php _e('Type something here','KleeiaDev') ?>" value="<?php echo stripslashes($_GET['keyword']) ?>" name="keyword" size="30" class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-12">
                            <?php echo ProjecTheme_get_budgets_dropdown($_GET['budgets'], 'form-control top-15' , 1); ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-12">
                            <select name="ending" class="form-control top-15">
                                <option value=""><?php _e('Ending in','KleeiaDev') ?></option>
                                <option value="1" <?php echo ($_GET['ending'] == 1 ? 'selected="selected"' : '') ?>><?php _e('1 day','KleeiaDev') ?></option>
                                <option value="7" <?php echo ($_GET['ending'] == 7 ? 'selected="selected"' : '') ?>><?php _e('7 days','KleeiaDev') ?></option>
                                <option value="30" <?php echo ($_GET['ending'] == 30 ? 'selected="selected"' : '') ?>><?php _e('30 days','KleeiaDev') ?></option>
                                <option value="180" <?php echo ($_GET['ending'] == 180 ? 'selected="selected"' : '') ?>><?php _e('6 Months','KleeiaDev') ?></option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-12">
                            <input type="submit" name="apply_filters" class="submit_green top-15 full_width text-center" value="<?php _e('Refine search','KleeiaDev') ?>" />
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

My goal is to refine results with 2 fixed conditions: `$taxonomy && $closed` [all posts in $taxonomy which are $closed] + eventually [$budgets && keyword && $ends].
When I submit, the form produces a url like `mydomain.com/?keyword=hello&budgets=&ending=7&apply_filters=Refine+search` but I get always all results in that taxonomy without filters applied. 
I don't know how to move on because I'm not very expert of queries. I've read the `query_posts` codex section without going further though.

Comment: Can somebody drive me through something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some tweaking I've discovered that I've totally forgotten the `relation` into `meta_query`. so I've just added

```
'meta_query' => array(
                    'relation' => 'AND',
                    $closed, 
                    $ends, 
                    $budgets, 
                ),
```

and it worked fine.